# Android NDK debugging from command line

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, gdb

I am having trouble debugging my native android application. I have tried in eclipse with no success, but at the moment I am simply trying to attach the debugger from the command line.

The error I am getting is as follows. I most definitely have the proper directories in my path.

> cygwin warning:   MS-DOS style path detected:
>   C:/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-local.mk   Preferred POSIX
>   equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-local.mk
>   CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this
>   warning.   Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX
>   paths:
>       http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames make: uname: Command not found make: rm: Command not found make: uname:
>   Command not found make: awk: Command not found
>   C:/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/init.mk:377: *** Android NDK: Aborting. 
>   .  Stop. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-gdb.py", line 837, in 
>       main()   File "C:\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-gdb.py", line 582, in main
>       APP_ABIS = get_build_var('APP_ABI').split(' ')   File "C:\android-ndk-r9d\ndk-gdb.py", line 309, in get_build_var
>       'DUMP_'+var] + GNUMAKE_FLAGS   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
>       raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output) subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command
>   '['C:\NVPACK\cygwin\bin\make.exe', '--no-print-dir', '-f',
>   'C:/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-local.mk', '-C', '.',
>   'DUMP_APP_ABI']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Comment: It tries to run make. Do you have awk?

Comment: Check this out http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/